# Проблема в установке ethernet драйверов Kali Linux на Mac air

Tags: драйвер, kali-linux, ethernet, macbook

Недавно решил установить Kali Linux на свой Macbook
В процессе установки ethernet драйвер автоматически найти не удалось.
В ручном режиме там предлагается список из 100+ разных ethernet драйверов из которых так же ни один не устанавливается(проверял все) и в итоге кали устанавливается без драйвера и нет подключения к wifi хотя до этого пробовал устанавливать Ubuntu все драйвера устанавливались как надо

Comment: непонятно, вам на ethernet или на wifi дрова нужны ? а `lspci -knn` что говорит ?

Comment: Почитайте внимательно пост

Comment: прочитал, начали _(100+ разных ethernet драйверов из которых так же ни один не устанавливается)_ за здравие, а кончили _(нет подключения к wifi)_ за упокой.